# Android 10 NFC App - Stops working when phone sleeps while in MS Intune Kiosk Mode

Tags: android, nfc, android-10.0, kiosk, intune

No one can figure this one out.

We are using [Microsoft Intune](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/configuration/device-restrictions-android-for-work) to lock some phones (Samsung) to a single NFC scanning android application.
Worked great using Android 9. However, with no change to Intune, the app does not work on Android 10.

It works - but as soon as the phone goes to sleep (as in 30 seconds), the NFC scanning function does not work. No vibration or sound whatsoever.
Only thing that pops up (sometimes) if I tap the power button off/on is a toast "no supported app for this NFC tag". Rest of the app works fine - just the NFC reader is disabled.

Restarting the phone fixes it - until it goes to sleep again. Pushing the power button to turn off the screen, does *not* break it either. The phone has to automatically go to sleep for the problem to occur.

Other apps have the same issue when NFC is used.

Any ideas on what would be causing this? What would shut down the entire NFC on sleep?
Maybe another clue - if I assign the xcover/bixby button to open settings, it usually "tricks" kiosk mode and opens settings when pressed. However upon the sleep, the trick no longer works.

Comment: Give it a try to [Daniel Bardyn answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73574594/android-12-kiosk-mode-nfc-stops-working-after-screen-timeout), the second workaround actually worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am having exactly the same issue.

This is my temporary solutions :

I added a button click to refresh the device admin App. Disabled cosu policies and clear home app. And reinit the device admin. And the NFC scan is back to work. But once it goes to sleep, the NFC stop working again. Then user may click the button to make NFC back to normal. At least no device restart is needed.

hope it helps. thanks.

Comment: I just ended up putting it in multi kiosk mode. Which locks it down somewhat - along with hiding apps. Will try to raise a ticket with MS.

Answer (score 0):

Along with a colleague we managed to workaround this, for some reason it only functions after sleep if the lock screen appears which it doesn't with kiosk, so, in your Intune config allow Enabled system navigation features - Home and overview buttons

Then in kiosk open the NFC app, touch the left hand button to bring up the app switcher and touch your NFC app to open. Then if you lock the screen and go to unlock it you will see the unlock screen and should find that NFC continues to function.

Answer (score 0):

Using Intune managed home screen kiosk with NFC and i experience the same issues.

A work around for us are to disable and enable the NFC scanner in order to get it to work.

It's a interesting thing that it stop working when going into sleepmode. Just in order to get NFC to work propertly you have to enable/white list all the NFC packages like android.nfc/com.samsung.android.knox.nfc, wondering if there is a Android/Samsung package that need to be whitelisten in order to enable the NFC tag again after sleepmode?

Answer (score 0):

We did get a solution on this from MS that seams to work.

1. Deploy "com.android.nfc" as Enterprise system app.
2. Add "com.android.nfc" to MHS Kiosk policy/device restriction policy
3. Set "Disable lock screen" to Disable in the MHS kiosk policy/Device restriction Policy

Answer (score 0):

It make no sense but you don't have to Disable lock Screen.
But, you just have to enable the option in Power Settings :  "Screen on While device plugged in" and select AC, Wireless and USB.
Of course, you have to deploy "com.android.nfc" as Enterprise system app and add "com.android.nfc" to MHS in Kiosk Policy/device restriction policy (Thanks Audun)
I did that and the NFC works well in Managed home screen.